# Custom Adapter for Gallery View in Android

Tags: android

hi i want to split my gallery with 5 images in 2 rows.
Please let me know how to do this in android using Gallery View & custom adapter for Gallery view.

Is there any sample code available please share it, i have already checked the previous posts in this site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you still need this and Pagination instead of scroll will work for you, you might look at: https://github.com/sfarooq/PaginatedGallery

I designed it using ViewPager so you can manipulate the adapter to send any kind of views you want including two row views.

If you must use scrolling galleries you could implement two separate gallery in a vertical orientation and send touch events from each to the other.